Using multiprocessing for training in pytorch
I want to try to finetine a model with images of arbitrary sizes.
Not so hard to write somthing like
...
y_pred = torch.cat([model(im) for im in imgs])
loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y)
...

but even simple model(batch)  kinda cpu-bound, so this is even slower.
I tried somthing like
pool.map(model, imgs)

which gives me error telling autograd can't be used between processes.
I've briefly looked dataparallel pages in pytorch documentation and came to the conclusion, that dataparallel cant be used in such a way.
So is there a way or not?

I would take a look at fabric. It handles a lot of stuff for you in terms of multiprocessing/multi node/multi gpu

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
...
model = torch.jit.script(model)
...
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor()
...
y_pred = torch.cat(list(pool.map(model, imgs)))
...

but this is not that faster as I expested.
